# php_memcache.dll vc6 X64?

Tags: php, memcached, 64-bit, wamp

I am running wamp server with php 5.3.0. My efforts running memcached were a fail :( After googeling I found out that the problem is that I need the correct php_memcache.dll which is a vc6 compiled for windows 7 X64. Does anyone know where can I find the dll?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running a 64 bit webserver and 64 bit php you need 64 bit extensions and a 64 bit service:

The common service and extensions will not work for you.

Install the 64 bit memcached service:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win64-1.4.4-14.zip

And one of these php extensions (to match your php version):

Php 5.3: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?o60feet9sw71six

Php 5.4: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?8d3vd26z3fg6bf1

---

Follow up for people looking for other 64 bit php extensions:

http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions

Referenced from:

http://www.anindya.com/category/windows/

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes, needs to be higher in Google. I've been searching for a little while here and all I could find were x86 DLL's.  But my search has ended here!

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found on [PHP web pages](http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/compiler), 64bit is not supported on VC6 platform. But to make things clean, you only need 64bit dlls only if you have the rest of the program compiled in 64bits. And as PHP can't be VC6+64bit, you 'only' have to find VC6 version of php_memcache.dll. I've tried to find some recent version of it, as my XAMPP is also VC6, but to no avail.

Comment: yeah, i believe they all offline. need someone with the knowledge to compile it i guess